# C struct automatic initialization values, array initializations

Tags: c, arrays, struct, initialization

If I were to have two structs

```
typedef struct {
  int number_of_lines;
  char lines[MAX_CHAPTER_LINES][MAX_STR_SIZE + 1];
} Chapter;

typedef struct {
  char name[MAX_STR_SIZE + 1];
  int number_of_chapters;
  Chapter chapters[MAX_CHAPTERS];
} Book;
```

And I created a Chapter variable:

```
Chapter x1;
```

What would the values of its two members be initialized to? Is it garbage? Or is it zero? In my code I got `0` for the `int`, but my TA told me it would be garbage?

Also, if I were to declare an array of chapters:

```
Chapter chapters[30];
```

Would it be filled with 30 structs with `0`/`NULL` valued elements? Or initialized with garbage valued elements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends. Unless initialized explicitly,

- If the variable has static (or thread) storage duration, the members will be initialized to `0` or equivalent.
- In case it has automatic storage duration, the contents will be left indeterminate (yes, *"indeterminate"* is more appropriate than *"garbage"*).

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.7.9/p10

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is
>   indeterminate. If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, then:
>
> — if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
>
> — if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
>
> — if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules,
>   and any padding is initialized to zero bits;
>
> — if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;